# using a list of names to open multiple files in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I want to open multiple files using a list of names and such that the names of the opened files will also incorporate the names in the list, as shown below:

```
List = ["Sin", "Cos", "Tan"]
for x in List:
    df_x = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\gtala\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TIME AI\\NIST_Tests\\constants\\x.txt")
```

So I want `x` to replace `x` in the name of the file and in the directory, such that eventually I will open `df_Sin` from `Sin.txt` and `df_Cos` from `Cos.txt`, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
List = ["Sin", "Cos", "Tan"]
base="C:\\Users\\gtala\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TIME AI\\NIST_Tests\\constants\\"
df = {}
for x in List:
    df[x] = pd.read_csv(base + x +".txt")
```

In the dictionary, *df*, above, the Sin variables are accessed using df['Sin'], for example, as follows:

```
print df['Sin']
```

Comment: I like this, because i need the for loop to do operations on each data frame. However, the name of each df is not modified to include the names in the list. for example when I ask for df_Sin i get an error message that name "'df_Sin' is not defined"

Comment: Sure, I have modified the answer to use a dictionary that stores each result in 'Sin', 'Cos' and 'Tan' assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to store this in a dictionary data structure instead.

```
path = "C:\\Users\\gtala\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TIME AI\\NIST_Tests\\constants"
file_names = ["Sin", "Cos", "Tan"]

df_dict = {f"df_{x}": pd.read_csv(f"{path}//{x}.txt") for x in file_names}
```

You can then access a dataframe of interest by using

```
df_dict['df_Sin']
```

Comment: This is the correct approach in my opinion. 2 suggestions to make it cleaner:
Use the new string interpolation: `f"df_{x}"` rather than `format` (same with filepath) and save the directory path as a variable outside the dict to make it cleaner

Comment: So `path = "C:\\Users\\gtala\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TIME AI\\NIST_Tests\\constants"` outside and then we have `df_dict = {f"df_{x}: pd.read_csv(f"{path}//{x}.txt" for x in file_names}`

Comment: Ah yeah that does looks nice. I haven't really used string interpolation before, thanks for pointing it out! You're more than welcome to edit if you like?

Answer (score 1):

#### `map`

```
f = "C:\\Users\\gtala\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\TIME AI\\NIST_Tests\\constants\\{}.txt".format
list(map(pd.read_csv, map(f, ["Sin", "Cos", 'Tan'])))
```